# How to make multithreaded web requests?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this code made so I can check information on users that are on my website. The code block below works, but I'm having trouble making it so I can do it faster with multi-threading.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Check();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void Check()
{
    string Users = @"D:\stuff\1.1\Info.txt";
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Users))
    {
        string[] Info = line.Split(':');
        string user = Combos[0];
        string pty = Combos[1];
        string PI = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"username\":\"" + user + "\",\"PTY\":\"" + pty + "\"}");
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://LocalServer"); // my local server
            Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            Request.Method = "POST";
            Request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://LocalServer"), new Cookie("LANGUAGE", "en"));
            Request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://LocalServer"), new Cookie("DEFLANG", "en"));
            Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
            string Response = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
            PI = response.Cookies["PI"].ToString().Replace("PI=", "");
            Match Token = (new Regex("{\"access_token\":\"([^\"]*)")).Match(Response);
            string Token1 = Token.Groups[1].ToString();
            HttpWebRequest RCapture = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://LocalServer/profiles" + PI + "/summary");
            RCapture.Method = "Get";
            RCapture.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            RCapture.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + Token1);
            HttpWebResponse RCap = (HttpWebResponse)RCapture.GetResponse();
            string CapR = (new StreamReader(RCap.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
            Match RInfo = (new Regex("(.*)")).Match(CapR);
            string ptyInfo = RInfo.Groups[1].ToString();
            float ptyInt = 0;
            Single.TryParse(ptyInfo, out ptyInt);
            if (ptyInt >= 10)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(user + ":" + pty + "   " + ptyInt);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                Console.WriteLine(user + ":" + pty + "   " + ptyInt);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about doing Async with `await` commands but I wasn't sure if that was the best option or how I should go about doing that.

Comment: This question gets asked at least once every day. there is a wealth of information available

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: @mjwills `Parallel.ForEach` is for compute operations not I/O-bound operations.  You would end up spinning up threads and blocking for the I/O to complete

Comment: Technically he asked for multi-threading. I am not saying that was the right question to ask - but for **that question** `Parallel.ForEach` is a correct answer. _Are there better ones? Sure._

Comment: @OP You don't.  You use `async/await` so as to avoid threads completely.  _[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)_

Comment: @mjwills It's not a good way to teach.   It's like how MS in their spin-up threading examples nearly always do a `Thread.Sleep()` (or Join() ewww).  The number of times we see beginners doing the same thing on SO due to picking up bad habits

Comment: @mjwills Just so you know the _"You don't"_ was directed at OP :)  Wishing you well